# Key-based login across all cPanel sites

Tags: cpanel, ssh-keys

We currently host >50 client sites within cPanel which we manage via SFTP using separate account username + passwords for each. It would be beneficial for us to switch to a key-based login and disable passwords.

How would you go about doing this so you could login in to any one of the client sites? The clients themselves never have access which is limited to our in-house developers.

Would it be a bad idea to share a single key between all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very bad idea to use same key for your all 50 sites, I will suggest you create separate key for your all sites and use that to login instead of password.

Comment: I felt it might be. So you are suggesting going through each account individually creating a new key pair, adding the public key to the account and then repeating the same steps for every developer? Ending up with 100s of keys?

Comment: If you want your all accounts security then you will have to use separate key for your all accounts.